# Query for employee who has maximum leaves

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, group-by, analytics

I have these tables with the following columns :

- Employee24 (EMPLOYEEID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, GENDER, JOBROLES);
- Leave25 (EMPLOYEEID,LEAVEID, LEAVETYPE, STARTDATE, ENDDATE);

I want to write a query to find the employee who has taken the maximum number of leave:

```
select emp.*, L.Startdate - L.Enddate 
from leave25 l, employee24 emp
where emp.employeeid = l.employeeid 
  and l.startdate - l.enddate = (select max(startdate - enddate) from  leave25)
```

Comment: Looks like your whole project rests on the benevolence of  StackOverflow contributors.

Comment: can i assume that for 1 day leave, Start and End Date will be same.? Please provide sample input and output.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nay use the following nested SQL with DENSE_RANK() function ( including ties (the same values) ) :

```
SELECT EMPLOYEEID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, LEAVE_DAY
  FROM
(
SELECT L.EMPLOYEEID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, 
       (ENDDATE - STARTDATE + 1) LEAVE_DAY,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (ENDDATE - STARTDATE + 1) DESC) DR
  FROM EMPLOYEE24 E JOIN LEAVE25 L ON ( E.employeeid = L.employeeid )
 GROUP BY L.EMPLOYEEID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ENDDATE - STARTDATE + 1                        
)            
WHERE DR = 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9fe509/2)

***Edit*** (according to your comment "*query for employees who has taken max number of leaves in past 1 month*") :

```
SELECT EMPLOYEEID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME,
              LEAVE_DAY
  FROM            
(              
  SELECT EMPLOYEEID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME,
         LEAVE_DAY, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY LEAVE_DAY DESC) DR 
    FROM
  (
    SELECT L.EMPLOYEEID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME,
         DECODE(SIGN(ENDDATE - ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),-1)+1),-1,0,
                     ENDDATE - ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),-1)+1) -
         DECODE(SIGN(STARTDATE - ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),-1)+1),1,
                    (STARTDATE - ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),-1)),0)
         as LEAVE_DAY
      FROM EMPLOYEE24 E JOIN LEAVE25 L ON ( E.employeeid = L.employeeid )
  ) 
)
WHERE DR = 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo 2*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3f16/1)

Comment: could you please update this query to employee who has taken max number of leaves in past 1 month?

Comment: I got it. Thanks.

Comment: @user2147357 lately I thought uisng DENSE_RANK rather than ROW_NUMBER is better, since it includes ties.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Select Top 1  e.EMPLOYEEID,e.Name,SUM(DATEDIFF(d,StartDate,EndDate)+1) as LeaveTaken 
from Leave25 l
INNER JOIN Employee24 e on l.EMPLOYEEID=e.EMPLOYEEID
Group By e.EMPLOYEEID,e.Name
Order by LeaveTaken desc
```